# Elasticsearch analyzer settings and matching data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I'm trying an example using the same settings as in the documentation when creating an index

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": { 
          "char_filter": [
            "emoticons"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "punctuation",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "punctuation": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "[ .,!?]"
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "emoticons": { 
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            ":) => _happy_",
            ":( => _sad_"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": { 
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then I save a data to the index

```
POST /my-index-000003/_doc/1
{
  "content": "I'm feeling :) today, but the weather is quite gloomy :("
}
```

However, when I search for :) or *happy*, I can't find a match. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At indexing time `:)` gets replaced with `_happy_` and `:(` with `_sad_`. So you cannot search for `:)` or `:(` anymore.

If you don't want your emoticons to be replaced, you need to use a synonyms token filter instead of a character filter.

If you search for `happy` that will not find `_happy_`, but if you search for `_happy_` that will work, I was able to reproduce and that worked with the following query:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "_happy_"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this will only work if your `content` field is configured with the `my_custom_analyzer` analyzer

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I can't find any matches in my search for `_happy_ `.Do you have any other suggestions regarding the situation?

Comment: Can you update your question with your mappings, as we only see your settings

Comment: I edited the part about mapping, problem solved, thanks